# What does launch.json have to do with debugging javascript?

Tags: javascript, windows, debugging, configuration, visual-studio-debugging

Trying to debug my javascript code in Visual Studio. Selected "Start Debugging" and I get the following error message "configuration 'Run Current File' is missing in launch.json" (not pictured--error msg vanished after 5 seconds). I also got redirected to this launch.json file but have no idea what I need to type here.

I already have installed Node.js. I have restarted my computer, as well as edited the syntax of my javascript before debugging.

I am very very new to programming and am not sure what could be missing. Help please!

Comment: The default launch.json file is usually good for most use cases, especially if you're a beginner

Answer (score 0):

`launch.json` is used for to launch an app for debugging. It has settings geared for things like mapping to your workspace source code or defining the Chrome port to use.

Check full details [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging)

Comment: As far as I can see, the question refers to Visual Studio, not the glorified notepad app "Visual Studio Code" (thank you Microsoft for the inspirational name). Your link clearly refers to vscode. Does that apply to Visual Studio as well?